# Capture Click on TreeView Item

Tags: silverlight, events, treeview, selecteditem

Is there a way to explicitly capture a click on a TreeView item?

Currently, I'm in a position where a TV represents a sort of options menu for users. Ordinarily, I would just use the **SelectedItemChanged** event on the TV, but there is the possibility of a user re-clicking an item twice in a row which won't raise this event. I considered the idea of putting an event listener on the stackpanel that contains the items in each node, but the problem is this event fires before a selected item changed on a node. So if you hit the stackpanel, you'll get the event, but won't be able to get the associated item. Any ideas on how to get out of this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle `MouseLeftButtonUp` event for the `TreeView`.

```
private void treeView1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = treeView1.SelectedItem;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

You can handle `MouseLeftButtonDown`, but `SelectedItem` will not be changed yet at that moment. What you can do is to access `e.OriginalSource` to find out what element was clicked. I checked the example below with a tree of `<TreeViewItem />`, so element was `TextBlock`. If you try the code below change the type casting according to your scenario.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    treeView1.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(treeView1_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
}

private void treeView1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedElement = (TextBlock)e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted the response to be specifically on the button down action? I don't want an unsavory delay in the UX.

Comment: @themaestro - I can show how can you handle MouseLeftButtonDown event, but you will have the same problem as you do now. The reason is because selected item is changed after `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, but before `MouseLeftButtonUp`.